# Highcharts: how to define x-axis for dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to automatically plot an array which is output from a sensor and is updated every second or so. The array is `x` elements long. This particular sensor measures the light intensity at `x` steps between some `min` and `max` wavelengths (that is, it measures the intensity at increments of `(max-min)/x`--in my case this increment is not an integer). I also have a static data set that is plotted on the same axes with the same x-axis requirements.

I am able to successfully graph this data dynamically, but the x-axis scale is wrong. Instead of ranging from `min` to `max`, Highcharts defaults to a range of `min` to `min+x`. I'd like to change the x-axis increment so that the scaling is correct.

Can a `min`, `max`, and `number of data points` or `step` be defined to generate the x-axis? Or is there a way to define the x- and y-axis values as individual arrays that are plotted against each other? Some other way? I have done lots of searching and experimenting but have come up short.

The relevant snippet of my code is below.

```
function showData(result) { // 'result' is an array that comes from the sensor
    var numbers = int(split(resultString, ","));
    chart.series[1].setData(numbers);
    socket.send('a'); // send a byte to tell it to start sending new data
    loop++; //increase loop every time the server receives data
    chart.setTitle({ text: 'Spectrum, reading #' + loop });
} //showData

$(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'area',
            load: function() {
                chart = this;
                showData();
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Spectrum, reading 0'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Wavelength [nm]',
                allowDecimals: false,
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 340,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '404 nm laser spectrum',
            data: [130,130,114,113,113,116,112,111,112,112,115,113,113,115,
                112,114,113,113,114,115,113,114,113,114,115,115,117,119,124,
                136,145,164,190,217,252,363,482,491,417,285,188,156,140,132,
                127,122,117,118,117,115,116,115,116,118,116,116,117,116,117,
                116,113,117,114,113,115,112,116,114,114,116,114,114,116,113,
                116,115,114,115,115,114,115,115,115,116,114,115,116,114,118,
                114,116,116,115,118,114,113,117,113,116,116,115,116,115,115,
                115,114,117,116,117,118,120,118,122,119,128,127,130,134,136,
                138,140,137,139,134,136,134,132,133,134,131,132,130,130,131,
                128,128,131,129,131,131,134,136,134,140,139,137,143,140,138,
                141,136,134,132,127,126,126,123,123,118,119,122,118,120,117,
                116,118,116,118,116,115,117,116,115,116,115,115,116,114,119,
                113,114,116,115,116,114,114,116,116,113,117,116,114,118,112,
                115,114,113,116,115,114,115,113,116,114,114,116,115,115,114,
                112,114,114,113,114,115,113,117,114,115,112,114,114,113,115,
                114,114,115,113,112,115,112,113,115,112,116,113,113,115,116,
                113,116,113,115,113,114,115,115,114,116,114,116,113,116,117,
                113,115,116,115,117,115,114,117,113,115,118,114,116,115,115,
                116,114,113,116,114,117,115,114,117,115,114,115,116,116,116,
                117,117,114,0],
                color: '#36D39F'
            }, {
                name: 'Current measured spectrum',
                data: numbers,
                color: '#4A235A'
            }]
        });
    });
```

EDIT: here's a demo showing how mine currently functions: https://jsfiddle.net/bgzgc1d9/2/. The x-axis should range from 340 to 850 with 288 data points evenly spaced on this interval

Comment: Your demo is not complete. You can mock dynamic data by addpoint in setInterval function. Also, you can try to control the x axis by updating its max dynamically. https://jsfiddle.net/bgzgc1d9/1/

Comment: @morganfree Maybe I wasn't clear in my original post but the every point in the dynamic array updates every second, i.e., the entire graph is refreshed instead of one point being appended every second. The x-axis should always range from 340 to 850 with 288 data points evenly spaced on this interval. Also, series[0] should be a persistent data set and series[1] is what updates every second. I have modified your demo to show how mine currently functions https://jsfiddle.net/bgzgc1d9/2/

Comment: Set min/max for the axis https://jsfiddle.net/bgzgc1d9/3/. If you do not know max/min of your data, find the min/max before the chart is created.

Comment: @morganfree setting the max/min of the axis doesn't appear to change anything. However I did just find the answer: adding `pointInterval: 1.7708` in `plotOptions.area` achieved the desired result